# Remove reversed duplicates from a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can anyone suggest a good solution to remove reversed duplicates from a data frame?

My data looks like this, where first and second columns are reversed duplicates.

```
TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3    TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4    96.491  228 8   0   202 429 417 190 3.049999999999999e-104  377
TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4    TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3    96.104  231 9   0   190 420 429 199 2.979999999999999e-104  377
```

I need to keep only one row, where third column has the higher value

```
TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3    TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4    96.491  228 8   0   202 429 417 190 3.049999999999999e-104  377
```

This the results when I use series.isin().

```
TRINITY_DN28139_c0_g1_i2    TRINITY_DN28139_c0_g1_i5    99.971  3465    1   0   1   3465    1   3465    0.0 6394
TRINITY_DN28139_c0_g1_i5    TRINITY_DN28139_c0_g1_i2    99.971  3465    1   0   1   3465    1   3465    0.0 6394
TRINITY_DN25313_c0_g1_i6    TRINITY_DN25313_c0_g1_i5    99.97   3315    1   0   1   3315    1   3315    0.0 6117
TRINITY_DN25313_c0_g1_i5    TRINITY_DN25313_c0_g1_i6    99.97   3315    1   0   1   3315    1   3315    0.0 6117
TRINITY_DN25502_c0_g1_i3    TRINITY_DN25502_c0_g1_i4    99.96799999999999   3078    1   0   1   3078    1   3078    0.0 5679
TRINITY_DN25502_c0_g1_i4    TRINITY_DN25502_c0_g1_i3    99.96799999999999   3078    1   0   1   3078    1   3078    0.0 5679
TRINITY_DN28726_c0_g1_i2    TRINITY_DN28726_c0_g1_i1    99.96600000000001   5805    2   0   1   5805    1   5805    0.0 10709
TRINITY_DN28726_c0_g1_i1    TRINITY_DN28726_c0_g1_i2    99.96600000000001   5805    2   0   1   5805    1   5805    0.0 10709
TRINITY_DN27942_c0_g1_i7    TRINITY_DN27942_c0_g1_i6    99.964  2760    1   0   1   2760    1   2760    0.0 5092
TRINITY_DN25118_c0_g1_i1    TRINITY_DN25118_c0_g1_i2    99.964  2770    1   0   81  2850    204 2973    0.0 5110
TRINITY_DN27942_c0_g1_i6    TRINITY_DN27942_c0_g1_i7    99.964  2760    1   0   1   2760    1   2760    0.0 5092
TRINITY_DN25118_c0_g1_i2    TRINITY_DN25118_c0_g1_i1    99.964  2770    1   0   204 2973    81  2850    0.0 5110
TRINITY_DN28502_c1_g1_i9    TRINITY_DN28502_c1_g1_i7    99.963  2678    1   0   1928    4605    2021    4698    0.0 4940
TRINITY_DN28502_c1_g1_i7    TRINITY_DN28502_c1_g1_i9    99.963  2678    1   0   2021    4698    1928    4605    0.0 4940
TRINITY_DN25619_c0_g1_i1    TRINITY_DN25619_c0_g1_i8    99.963  2715    1   0   1   2715    1   2715    0.0 5009
TRINITY_DN25619_c0_g1_i8    TRINITY_DN25619_c0_g1_i1    99.963  2715    1   0   1   2715    1   2715    0.0 5009
TRINITY_DN23022_c0_g1_i5    TRINITY_DN23022_c0_g1_i1    99.962  2622    1   0   1   2622    1   2622    0.0 4837
```

Comment: is it always that every 2 rows or more is reverse duplicated? can there be a 3rd row where col1 value is repeated but col2 value is not? if no check below answer

Comment: There is no more than two row where first and second columns are reversed duplicates and there can be a 3rd row where col1 value is repeated but col2 value is not and or col2 value is repeated but col1 value is not.

Comment: can you please post some more data so we can test and get a solution? thanks.

Comment: I added the results to my question when I use  series.isin()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. It's completely in pandas (should be faster)
This also corrects bugs in my previous answer but the concept of taking the labels as a pair remains the same.

```
In [384]: df['pair'] = df[[0, 1]].apply(lambda x: '{}-{}'.format(*sorted((x[0], x[1]))), axis=1)
```

Get only max values per duplicated result:

```
In [385]: dfd = df.loc[df.groupby('pair')[2].idxmax()]
```

If you need the names to be in separate columns:

```
In [398]: dfd[0] = dfd['pair'].transform(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
In [399]: dfd[1] = dfd['pair'].transform(lambda x: x.split('-')[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`series.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to find same entries in both columns and drop duplicates:

```
df=df.sort_values('col3',ascending=False)
df.loc[df['col1'].isin(df['col2']).drop_duplicates().index]
```

Where `col1` is the first column and `col2` is the second

Output:

```
0   TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3    TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4    96.49   228 8   0   202 429 417 190 0.00    377
```

Comment: Thanks so much, not sure 'col2' in first line should be col3 to sort values!! However second line does not work! It doesn't drop duplicates!

Comment: @aboozarsoorni yes should be col3, also why is it not dropping duplicates? is the data exactly same or a little different?

Comment: may Col3 values be exactly the same or a little different

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that labels in column 0 and column 1 must be taken as a pair so an `isin` alone would not work

First, a list of label pairs is needed to compare to (`forward` in the code). Given that `(a,b)` is the same as `(b,a)`, all instances will just be replaced by `(a,b)`

Then all labels that are duplicated are renamed in the order `a,b` even if the higher row is `b,a`. This is necessary to do the grouping step later.

```
In [293]: df['pair'] = df[[0, 1]].apply(l, axis=1)
```

Then to account for the value of column 2 (third column from left), the original data is grouped and the min of the group is kept. This will be the rows to be removed.

```
In [297]: dfi = df.set_index(['pair',2])

In [298]: to_drop = df.groupby([0,1])[2].min().reset_index().set_index([0,1,2]).index

In [299]: dfi['drop'] = dfi.index.isin(to_drop)

In [300]: dfr = dfi.reset_index()
```

Rows are dropped by the index number where the 'drop' column is True.
The temporary 'drop' column is also removed.

```
In [301]: df_dropped = dfr.drop(np.where(dfr['drop'])[0], axis=0).drop('drop', axis=1)

In [302]: df_dropped
Out[302]:
                         0                         1       2    3   4   5    6    7    8    9              10   11
0  TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3  TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4  96.491  228   8   0  202  429  417  190  3.050000e-104  377
```

Comment: Thanks so much! What is 'forward' in 'r' list (first line)?

Comment: I edited the answer. `forward` creates a list of unique label pairs for all label pairs sorted alphabetically. So `(TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3, TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4)` and  `(TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4, TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3)` will be stored as the just  `(TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3, TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4)`

Comment: `r` creates a list of pairs to modify col 0 and 1 (the labels) if it is duplicated. So `(TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3, TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4)` and  `(TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4, TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3)` will have the same labels  `(TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i3, TRINITY_DN16813_c0_g1_i4)` for col 0 and 1 respectively

Comment: By the way, I just realized from looking at your data that you are doing a reciprocal blast on assembled sequences.

Comment: Right, and when I have a big data, this code will take too much time!

Comment: So sorry, I think this code does not work well. My original data has 70487 rows. If I suppose all rows are duplicated (the worse scenario), after removing duplicates I should have around 35000 rows. This code gives me around 4000 rows. Can I send to you my whole original data for checking?

Comment: @aboozar-soorni Can you try my edit on a subset of your dataset?

Comment: Thanks great! Edit code works very well! Only a bit change:                                                                                         dfd = df.sort_values(2).drop_duplicates('pair').drop('pair', axis=1)

Comment: I'll put the edit as a new answer. If it solved your problem, please approve the new answer instead of this one.

Comment: Sorry but please take note that it should be `idxmax` and not `idxmin`! The new code identifies what rows to keep instead of what to delete.